Change of variables by scaling.
I'm going through the book Applied Partial Differential Equations: with Fourier Series and Boundary value problems by Richard Haberman. In chapter 7 this is said about this equation (Next step is explaining Bessel's differential equation):
$r^{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2} f}{\mathrm{d} r^{2}}+r\frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d} r}+(\lambda r^{2}-m^{2})f=0$ (7.7.23)
"There is some additional analysis of (7.7.23) that can be performed. Equation (7.7.23)
contains two parameters, m and $\lambda$.We already know that m is an integer, but the allowable
values of $\lambda$ are as yet unknown. It would be quite tedious to solve (7.7.23) numerically
for various values of $\lambda$ (for different integral values of m). Instead, we might notice that
the simple scaling transformation,
$z =\sqrt{\lambda}r$, (7.7.24)
removes the dependence of the differential equation on $\lambda$:
$z^{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2} f}{\mathrm{d} z^{2}}+z\frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d} z}+(z^{2}-m^{2})f=0$"
My problem is that I do not understand this variable change. If $z =\sqrt{\lambda}r$ then $r =\frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$ and the equation should become (note fractions in the first two terms):
$\frac{z^{2}}{\lambda}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2} f}{\mathrm{d} z^{2}}+\frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d} z}+(z^{2}-m^{2})f=0$
Clearly there is a lack in my knowledge when the author says "scaling transformation". Is there anyone willing to explain what I am missing in this?

You need to take the transformation rule into account. Because of the scaling $\mathrm{d}{z}\not = \mathrm{d}r$ but rather $\mathrm{d}z=\sqrt{\lambda}~\mathrm{d}r$ and if I did not mix up my calculations this takes care of the extra factors of $\lambda$.
Note that for the second derivate $\sqrt{\lambda}$ pops out twice.

AH of course, now it all makes sense. Thank you!
